# Yichud when raising a child

Tags: age, yichud-seclusion

I once heard that when you start raising a child while the child is still under the age of 2, there is less concerns about *Yichud* later on. I have not found any source for this and was wondering if anyone ever heard of this and from where this is coming from.

I assume that this is based on the following:

> כל המגדל יתום בתוך ביתו מעלה עליו הכתוב כאילו ילדו" (גמ' בסנהדרין דף י"ט ע"ב). משמע שדינו של
>   המגדל (מאמץ) כדין יולד. השאלה היא האם זה "כאילו" ילדו, או "ממש" ילדו.
>   ונפ"מ לאיסור ייחוד.

There are alot of sources confirming that and some even say that it counts for *Pirya Veribya*, and many sources explains that "*Hamegadel Yusom*" does not necessarily have to be someone that don't have a father.

But the "**age**" is not mentioned anywhere. I can imagine that if you take in a 18 year old boy it won't be considered "raising" him, so it has to be a starting point...

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: For others - the text you quote comes from http://www.mygod.co.il/אימוץ-ילדים-בסיכון-לאור-ההלכה/ but I can't see who this is.

Comment: Where is your quote from?

Comment: FWIW the Shulchan Aruch brings down that Yichud is permissible with a girl under 3 and a boy under 9 (EH 22:11), but nobody AFAICT qualifies this ruling with “if they were familiar from before then they can continue secluding themselves after.” OTOH I recall a Midrash which quotes a woman who said that a man she grew up with rejected her in favor of a less-pretty woman, because since he knew her in her youth, she was less pretty in his eyes.